# Overriding namespace with yaml

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, parameter-passing

## Problem statement

I want the options supported in a python module to be overridable with an `.yaml` file, because in some cases there are too many options to be specified with non-default values.

I implemented the logic as follows.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# some parser.add statements that comes with default values
parser.add_argument("--config_path", default=None, type=str,
                    help="A yaml file for overriding parameters specification in this module.")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Override parameters
if args.config_path is not None:
    with open(args.config_path, "r") as f:
        yml_config = yaml.safe_load(f)
    for k, v in yml_config.items():
        if k in args.__dict__:
            args.__dict__[k] = v
        else:
            sys.stderr.write("Ignored unknown parameter {} in yaml.\n".format(k))
```

The problem is, for some options I have specific functions/lambda expressions to convert the input strings, such as:

```
parser.add_argument("--tokens", type=lambda x: x.split(","))
```

In order to apply corresponding functions when parsing option specifications in YAML, adding so many `if` statements does not seem a good solution. Maintaining a dictionary that changes accordingly when new options are introduced in `parser` object seems redundant. Is there any solution to get the `type` for each argument in `parser` object?

Comment: You can also define your own actions passed to `add_argument` with the `action` parameter, these are more powerful than what you can do with `type` you might want to look into that. You can find, and apply, these in the same way on your values taken from the YAML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the elements that you add to the parser with `add_argument` start with `--` then they
are actually optional and usually called options. You can find these walking over 
the result of the `_get_optonal_actions()` method of the `parser` instance.

If you `config.yaml` looks like:

```
tokens: a,b,c
```

, then you can do:

```
import sys
import argparse
import ruamel.yaml


sys.argv[1:] = ['--config-path', 'config.yaml']  # simulate commandline

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--config-path", default=None, type=str,
                    help="A yaml file for overriding parameters specification in this module.")
parser.add_argument("--tokens", type=lambda x: x.split(","))
args = parser.parse_args()


def find_option_type(key, parser):
    for opt in parser._get_optional_actions():
        if ('--' + key) in opt.option_strings:
           return opt.type
    raise ValueError

if args.config_path is not None:
    with open(args.config_path, "r") as f:
        yml_config = yaml.load(f)
    for k, v in yml_config.items():
        if k in args.__dict__:
            typ = find_option_type(k, parser)
            args.__dict__[k] = typ(v)
        else:
            sys.stderr.write("Ignored unknown parameter {} in yaml.\n".format(k))

print(args)
```

which gives:

```
Namespace(config_path='config.yaml', tokens=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Please note:

- I am using the new API of `ruamel.yaml`. Loading this way is actually faster
  than using `from ruamel import yaml; yaml.safe_load()` although your config files
  are probably not big enough to notice.
- I am using the file extension `.yaml`, as recommended in the official [FAQ](http://yaml.org/faq.html). You should do so as well, unless you cannot (e.g. if your 
  filesystem doesn't allow that).
- I use a dash in the option string `--config-path` instead of an underscore, this is 
  somewhat more natural to type and automatically converted to an underscore to get valid
  identifier name

You might want to consider a different approach where you parse `sys.argv` by hand for
`--config-path`, then set the defaults for all the options from the YAML config file and
then call `.parse_args()`. Doing things in that order allow you to override, on
the commandline, what has a value in the config file. If you do things your way, you always
have to edit a config file if it has all correct values except for one.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. BTW, I'll correct the terminologies in my post accordingly.

Comment: But `.parse_args()` does not convert/apply the type argument, correct? So the args will then just be what yaml converts them to? This may be even more problematic, when argparse parses via `append` ox `extend`, right? Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @ThomasHilger If you have a question, please post it as such, your comment doesn't really make sense and a (non-)working example would help. Do you think there is a problem with yaml loading something as an integer and that not being converted by the explicit call to option type the parser expects although it is cast with `typ(v)`) ?